# How to set default file type for new files in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I sometimes edit JSON files in VS Code, I would like to set the default file type to be Json (e.g. when clicking <kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>N</kbd>)

[image]

I didn't find any related setting, I use <kbd>CTRL K</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> but it's not very productive.

Is there a way to set the default file type?

**EDITED:**
The solution is to use `"files.defaultLanguage": "json"`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Click `File` –> `Preferences` –> `Settings`  or `CTRL + ,`

Click to open the settings file and look for `files.defaultLanguage`

Move the cursor to this line or mouse hover on it, click the pencil sign shown  on the left, click the `Copy to Settings`, then add the file type in the right pane. such as

```
"files.defaultLanguage": "JSON",
```

`CTRL + S` after finishing

Comment: On mac os i found that the configuration was actually case sensitive and was accepted only when using lower case. VS code version  1.50.1

Comment: On Linux it also only works in lower case.

Comment: Weird that you have to specify "markdown" to get "Markdown" as your default, as of version 1.41.0 for mac